# Criteria query For Many To Many Relationship

Tags: java, hibernate-criteria, criteria-api

I have three entities: Task, Workflow, and Tag. Task and Workflow have ManyToOne and OneToMany Relationships. Workflow and Tag have ManyToMany Relationship.

I want to retrieve the record based on tagId.

Task:

```
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity(name = "xflow_task")
public class Task {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long taskId;
    private String taskName;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "workflow_id")
    private Workflow workflow;
}
```

Workflow:

```
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity(name = "xflow_workflow")
public class Workflow {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long workflowId; // 123

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "workflow", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Task> tasks;
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "xflow_workflow_tag",
              joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "workflow_id"), 
              inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id"))
    private List<Tag> tag;
}
```

Tag :

```
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity(name = "xflow_tag")
public class Tag {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer tagId;
    private String tagName;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tag",fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Workflow> workflow;
}
```

The Criteria Query is like below:

```
public Long criteriaForCount(SearchCriteria searchCriteria) {
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Long> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Long.class);
        Root<Task> root = criteriaQuery.from(Task.class);
       List<Predicate> predicateList = new ArrayList<>();   

       if(CoreUtil.isNonEmpty(taskSearchCriteria.getTagIdList())) {      
       predicateList.add(root.join("workflow").join("tag").in(taskSearchCriteria.getTagIdList()));
        }
        
        Predicate[] predicateArr = new Predicate[predicateList.size()];
        Predicate predicate = criteriaBuilder.and(predicateList.toArray(predicateArr));

        criteriaQuery.where(predicate);
        criteriaQuery.select(criteriaBuilder.count(root));

        return entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getSingleResult();
    }
```

A workflow can have many tags.
The query is running fine but returning multiple duplicates
entries from the database. I want to find the distinct task which has tagId(i.e taskSearchCriteria.getTagIdList()) which I pass as a list.

**CoreUtil is a helper class where we just check whether the object or collection is empty or not.**

Answer (score 0):

I think that the method that you put has nothing to do with it, since it returns a count of inputs. I would do something like this:

```
public List<Task> getTaskByTag(SearchCriteria searchCriteria) {

    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    //If you want records it has to be of type Task, Long would be for the number of records
    CriteriaQuery<Task> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Task.class);

    Root<Task> root = criteriaQuery.from(Task.class);
    
    Join<Task,Workflow> joinWF = root.join("workflow");
    Join<Workflow,Tag> joinTag = joinWF.join("tag");
    // The code is clearer when more complex queries are made if you store the joins in variables
    List<Predicate> predicateList = new ArrayList<>();   

   if(CoreUtil.isNonEmpty(taskSearchCriteria.getTagIdList())) {    
      //Access properties instead of using implicit access, for code clarity  
      predicateList.add(joinTag.get("tagId").in(taskSearchCriteria.getTagIdList()));
   }

   //The and clause is automatically added between all the elements of the list
   criteriaQuery.where(predicateList.toArray(new Predicate[predicateList.size()]));

   criteriaQuery.select(root).distinct(true);

   return entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
}
```